# Change font size in Xfce Terminal using Ctrl + mouse wheel?

Tags: fonts, mouse-wheel, xfce4-terminal

In Xfce Terminal, is it possible to change the font size using `Ctrl + mouse-wheel` as you would do in a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this feature is well hidden, and described in the issue tracker: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12869

use `Ctrl+Shift+Wheel-Up/Down` and it is static in the code at least back in 2016; but haven't found any setting in the actual version that would show otherwise.

to disable/enable you need to adjust the `MiscMouseWheelZoom` option in `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc`

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. You may want to file a feature request on [Xfce's bug tracker](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/).